# How to convert string from list to type of numbers like "sbyte" to type sbyte?

Tags: c#, string, methods, types

I made a working exercise but my code looks like not good as it could be.  There are a lot of `WriteLine` statements in my code and I would like to create a method. But how to convert - for example - string "sbyte" to type sbyte I do not know.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Exercise02
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string strFormat = "{0,-10} | {1,-4} | {2,30} | {3,30} |";

            HorizontalLIne();
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "Type", "Size", "Min", "Max"));
            HorizontalLIne();

            // I would like to write a method of this block of code
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "sbyte", sizeof(sbyte), sbyte.MinValue, sbyte.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "byte", sizeof(byte), byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "short", sizeof(short), short.MinValue, short.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "ushort", sizeof(ushort), ushort.MinValue, ushort.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "int", sizeof(int), int.MinValue, int.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "uint", sizeof(uint), uint.MinValue, uint.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "long", sizeof(long), long.MinValue, long.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "ulong", sizeof(ulong), ulong.MinValue, ulong.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "float", sizeof(float), float.MinValue, float.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "double", sizeof(double), double.MinValue, double.MaxValue));
            WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "decimal", sizeof(decimal), decimal.MinValue, decimal.MaxValue));

            HorizontalLIne();

        }
        private static void HorizontalLIne()
        {
            WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }

    }

}
```

My plan was make a list of strings, like "sbyte", "byte" "int"... and write a method.
I have tried the following:

```
string type = "sbyte";
private static void WriteLineOfType(string strFormat, string type) 
{
  Type typeFromString = Type.GetType(type);
  WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat,
          type,
          sizeof(typeFromString),
          typeFromString.MinValue,
          typeFromString.MaxValue));
}
```

But this method does not work.
How I could write the right method that gets the string for example `sbyte` and write to console `sizeof(sbyte)`, `sbyte.MinValue`, `sbyte.MaxValue`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that in .NET,

1. the primitive numeric types do not implement a common interface that exposes their common members like `+`, `-`, `MinValue`, `MaxValue`, etc.

and

2. static members cannot be part of interfaces. This includes operators like `+` as well as static properties like `MinValue`.

So there is no way to create a good abstraction over numeric types.  This is really unfortunate, but may be resolved if the proposed Shapes feature is added in C#8 or C#9 (https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/164)

It is possible to hack a solution together with reflection, but I would advise against that.  It will probably end up being more code that what you already have, and it will be difficult to change.

The best thing you could probably do is encapsulate some of your string formatting like this:

```
string FormatValueRange<T>(T min, T max) 
   where T : struct
{
     var type = typeof(T);
     return String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-4} | {2,30} | {3,30} |", type.Name, sizeof(T), min, max);
} 

HorizontalLIne();
WriteLine(String.Format(strFormat, "Type", "Size", "Min", "Max"));
HorizontalLIne();   
WriteLine(FormatValueRange<sbyte>(sbyte.MinValue, sbyte.MaxValue);
WriteLine(FormatValueRange<short>(short.MinValue, short.MaxValue);
WriteLine(FormatValueRange<int>(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
//...
HorizontalLIne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (partially) Reflection based solution. Note that you can't use the C# language type names with Reflection, you must use the .Net framework names they correspond to.

```
void Main() {
    var typeNames = new[] { "sbyte", "byte", "int16", "uint16", "int32", "uint32", "int64", "uint64", "single", "double", "decimal" };

    foreach (var aTypeName in typeNames)
        WriteLineOfType(aTypeName);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
void WriteLineOfType(string aTypeName) {
    var typeFromString = Type.GetType($"System.{aTypeName}", false, true);
    if (typeFromString != null)
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,-4} | {2,30} | {3,30} |",
                aTypeName,
                Marshal.SizeOf(Activator.CreateInstance(typeFromString)),
                typeFromString.GetField("MinValue").GetValue(typeFromString),
                typeFromString.GetField("MaxValue").GetValue(typeFromString)));
}
```